# Pack/Unpack and base64 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, base64, pack, unpack

I have a string `a = "hello"`. I can convert it to base 2 or base 16 using `unpack`:

```
a.unpack('B*')
# => ["0110100001100101011011000110110001101111"]

a.unpack('H*')
# => ["68656c6c6f"]
```

To convert to base 64, I tried `pack`:

```
[a].pack('m0')
# => "aGVsbG8="
```

but the result is not what I expected. I thought that if I have some binary representation or a string, to represent it in divided parts, I should use `unpack`. But it turned out not. Please help me understand it.

Comment: This is what base64 looks like; it uses 6-bit characters to encode an 8-bit stream (4 characters for every 3 bytes, basically).  What were you expecting?

Comment: Sawa edited my question incorrectly. My expectation was not about the result, expectation was about why we use pack to convert to base64 and use unpack for base16 and base2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per OP's clarified question, "Why do we use `#pack` to get base64 and `#unpack` to get other representations of raw data?"

The surface level reason is because `Array#pack` is a method that returns a `String`, while `String#unpack` is a method that returns an `Array`.

There are stronger conceptual reasons underlying this. The key principle is that base64 is not an array of raw bytes. Rather, it's a 7-bit-ASCII-safe string that can represent arbitrary bytes if properly (de)coded.

Each base64 character maps to a sequence of six bits. At the byte level, that's a 4:3 ratio of characters to raw bytes. Since integer powers of 2 don't divide by 3, we end up with padding more often than not, and you can't slice base64 in arbitrary places to get ranges of bytes out of it (you'd have to figure out which bytes you want in groups of three and go get the associated base64 characters in groups of four).

Arbitrary sequences of data are, fundamentally, arrays of bytes. Base64-encoded sequences are, fundamentally, strings: data sequences constrained to the range of bytes safely transmissible and displayable as text.

Base64 is the encapsulation (or "packing") of a data array into a string.

Answer (score 1):

The encoded text is correct, to validate use below online tool:
https://www.base64encode.org/

**text:**
hello

**Encoded Base64:**
aGVsbG8=

Useful resource:
https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/4-what-the-pack.html

Comment: Thanks for answer. But my source question was not about the result of pack (Sawa incorrectly edited my question). My true question was about why for converting string/binary to base64 Ruby uses pack but for comverting to base2 or base16 it uses unpack. Why not `a.unpack('m0')`, for example